# setAttribute for multi attribute component not working for vec3

Tags: three.js, aframe, setattribute

I am trying to add a multi-attribute component to an entity through the following code -

within a-frame scene -

```
<a-entity id="hornets"></a-entity>
```

within controller -

```
var hornets = document.querySelector('#hornets');      
hornets.setAttribute('crtmodelcopy', {id: 'ball', jitter: 5 1.2 0.4, modelCenter: 2 0.5 -50, src:'#hornet'});
```

The code for the component is as follows -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('crtmodelcopy', {
  schema: {
          id: {type:'string'},
          jitter: {type:'vec3'},
          modelCenter: {type:'vec3'},
          src: {type:'string'}
          },
  init: function() {
          ......
   }
```

But, I get the following error in console -

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong here. I have tried other combinations but to no avail. In some cases the component gets attached without any attributes. I think the problem is due to jitter and modelCenter attributes being vec3 fields so I need to pass the data also in the same format.

Could someone kindly help?

Thanks,
Niraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you're not passing a `vec3`, just three numbers which are an unexpected value, because the parser expects one vector.

---

Either pass a `vec3`:

```
setAttribute("test", {"jitter": new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 )})
```

or a string version of a vector:

```
setAttribute("test", {"jitter": "0 1 0"})
```

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/fevx5ryj/7/). The console shows that both vectors are properly passed into the `update` function.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I changed the setattribute code to - hornets.setAttribute('crtmodelcopy', {"id": 'ball', "jitter": "5 1.2 0.4", "modelCenter": "2 0.5 -50", "src":'#hornet'});   Should I move all the logic in the component from init function to update function for it to be able to read the data?

Comment: good idea since the `update` is called both upon init, and update (like setAttribute). You can move the logic to some external functions, and update only the  variables that change in the update